# PowerApps default dropdown Items

Tags: drop-down-menu, dropdown, default, powerapps

The question i have is am trying to make an IF statement for a default item in a dropdwon menu.

In Items:

```
Table(
    {
        Text: "Renouvellement",
        Val: 1
    },
    {
        Text: "Nouveau Patient",
        Val: 2
    },
    {
        Text: "Non Renseigner",
        Val: 3
    }
)
```

in Default:

```
If(
    ThisItem.ORD_TYPE_SID2 = 1,
    "1",
    If(
        ThisItem.ORD_TYPE_SID2 = 2,
        "2",
        If(
            ThisItem.ORD_TYPE_SID2 = 3,
            "3"
        )
    )
)
```

What am trying to do is if the ORD_TYPE_SID is = to 1 or 3, then use the list index 1 or 3.
How can i do that? but if i do show value the results is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the PowerApps [LookUp()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) Function. It brings back the first **record** (or **field**) in a Table that matches a **condition**.

**Try:**

- Changing the `Default` property to:

```
LookUp(
    Table(
        {
            Text: "Renouvellement",
            Val: 1
        },
        {
            Text: "Nouveau Patient",
            Val: 2
        },
        {
            Text: "Non Renseigner",
            Val: 3
        }
    ), 
    Val = ORD_TYPE_SID2.Selected.Value,
    Text
)
```

**Note:**

- The data type (numeric) of the `Val` field

  - This must match the data type in `ORD_TYPE_SID2` dropdown
- Also, probably best **not** to use a column called "Text" as this is a reserved word (the [Text()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-text) Function).

  - It will still *work* but may be unreliable or lead to confusion down the road

**Illustration:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and illustration, I will try this and let you.